# Can I replace my missing eye with a magic one?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, injury

So I tried to take on a small group of bandits, and during the fight I had my right eye cut out. The DM told me it can't grow back, so I asked him about anything I could replace it with. He said maybe some sort of magical eye would work. Are there any official magic eyes?

Comment: For reference, what class and level are you?
And do you want to keep it to official stuff only or would you also be fine with homebrew / magic item creation suggestions?

Comment: Opening this up to homebrew magical eyes would make this question unanswerable and close-able, though.

Comment: Did the DM place any explicit constraints on what would be allowed?  I mean it sounds like you're outside of RAW territory.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your best bet is the [Ersatz Eye](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ersatz-eye), a common magic item listed on page 137 of Xanathar's Guide to everything:

> *Wondrous item, common (requires attunement)*
>
> This artificial
>   eye replaces a real one that was lost or removed. While the ersatz eye
>   is embedded in your eye socket, it can’t be removed by anyone other
>   than you, and you can see through the tiny orb as though it were a
>   normal eye.

Comment: "requires attunement" -- warning, that is an expensive opportunity cost.

Comment: "it can’t be removed by anyone other than you" Man, that's even better than a regular real eye!

Comment: That *can* be a high opportunity cost in a high-level or high-magic game, but at lower levels or in a less magic-filled world where there aren't a lot of a attunement-required items to go around, it's not really a problem. By the time it is (or if you're in a world with many magic items), you might have other options.

Comment: Well, they can't remove Ersatz Eye but they can remove your eye socket from around it.

Answer (score 26):

### Magic items that let you see

The classic official eye replacement is the [Eye of Vecna](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/eye-of-vecna), though it's an artifact, and a nasty one at that (DMG 224):

> To attune to the eye, you must gouge out your own eye and press the artifact into the empty socket. The eye grafts itself to your head and remains there until you die. Once in place, the eye transforms into a golden eye with a slit for a pupil, much like that of a cat. If the eye is ever removed, you die.

...

> Properties of the Eye. Your alignment changes to neutral evil, and you gain the following benefits:...

The Eye of Vecna also grants you a number of powerful abilities, too. It seems unlikely that you could access such a powerful item if you're getting seriously hurt by bandits, though.

Another less rare item that helps you see is the [Robe of Eyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes), which is only Rare (DMG 193):

> This robe is adorned with eyelike patterns. While you wear the robe, you gain the following benefits:
> The robe lets you see in all directions, and you have advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that
> rely on sight...

In addition to official items, I have created other replacement eyes for my players. I realize that's a little outside of the scope of your question, but I suspect that such eyes are a common kind of homebrew.

### A spellcaster can regrow your eye

Instead of a magic item, DMG 272 details variant rules for losing and restoring an eye:

> **Lose an Eye.** You have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight and on ranged attack rolls. Magic such as the *[regenerate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/regenerate)* spell can restore the lost eye. If you have no eyes left after sustaining this injury, you're blinded.

The DMG presents these rules only as options, so they aren't binding and they require your DM's approval. Still finding someone who can cast a 7th level spell for you will certainly be easier than tracking down the Eye of Vecna.

The *regenerate* spell is described as follows:

> You touch a creature and stimulate its natural healing ability. The target regains 4d8 + 15 hit points. For the duration of the spell, the target regains 1 hit point at the start of each of its turns (10 hit points each minute).
>
> The target's severed body members (fingers, legs, tails, and so on), if any, are restored after 2 minutes. If you have the severed part and hold it to the stump, the spell instantaneously causes the limb to knit to the stump.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the Eye of Vecna would work. After all, it says that you have to gouge out your own eye, however, the eye that you would want to replace is presumably long gone. 
That further raises the question, if you still have your eye lying around, could you put it back in (non-functioning) and then gouge it out so you could implant the eye of Vecna?

Comment: That's the grossest hypothetical I've ever had to consider.

Comment: Sorry you werent the answer, im gonna look into the eye of vecna though, i might just get thr Ersatz eye, but that kinda seems boring. Thank You

Comment: @Eimsmaul when you look into the Eye of Vecna, the Eye of Vecna looks into you.

Comment: Eye of Vecna probably wants the sacrifice of the eye. Part of the cost.